# Connecting to a serversocket from internet to a system connected to internet via LAN

Tags: java, sockets

I want to connect to a server which is connected to internet via LAN. 
So in the client side i need to write code like 
new Socket("i dont know the ip",PORT_NO)
Here which ip address should i give? Its obvious that i can't give both LAN ip address as well as local address of the server.

Answer (score 1):

You server should be running on a machine with public IP. You cannot give private IP i.e address server got using DHCP when it is connected to LAN. You may need to do more configuration on your router to get the packet to your listening java server.

Comment: is there any other way to connect without configuring the router? I wonder how p2p networks work.

Comment: p2p server identifies your current ip and make it available to other users. P2P can work with varying IP, because whenever you launch your client, its current IP address(public, gateway) is published to other users to connect. Then MAC address in the packets is used to deliver the packets to your computer by the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide your LAN ip adress, because the localhost ip is the same for every device.

Comment: You can't connect that way. LAN ip is common to all systems connected in the lan.